# Asynchronous call inside Meteor.onCreateUser hook

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, user-accounts

In my meteor app, I'm trying to register a user on the server, do some work and add some additional properties to the user object passed into onCreateUser, and then go to a 'welcome' page specially adapted to the new user. Using Meteor 7.0.1 and Iron-router (latest)

My client code looks something like this :

```
// var userId = Meteor.registerUser(registrationOptions);
// Router.go('/welcome/'+userId);
```

Server code like this

```
// Meteor.onCreateUser(options, user){
//   if (options.profile) user.profile = options.profile;
    // a 3rd party method outside of Meteor
//   callToOutsideMethod(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(e, res){
//      user.results = res;
//      // do other stuff
//      user.foo = blah;
//      user.bar = baz;
//      return user;
//     }, function(err){ console.log(err); });
```

When I return the user object, I'm expect meteor to create the record, then log the new user in...

But what happens is that the screen becomes all distorted for a second, and then we jump to the new url '/welcome/the_new_user_id'...

But it throws an error on the script where I'm trying to access anything aside from user_id. Looking on the Mongo cli, none of the new properties have been added, even 'username' and 'login-tokens' etc do not appear on the new user. And the newly created user has ONLY an _id and nothing else... very weird.

Any ideas on what could be causing this weird behaviour ?

Comment: Please make the title of your question more specific in order for others to find it, e.g. "Asynchronous call inside Meteor.onCreateUser".
You should also add some more tags, try with `accounts`/`users` and `async`/`asynchronous`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're not actually returning anything inside `onCreateUser`. The inner function returns some value which then simply stands there.

**Solution?**

*If* the inner function (`callToOutsideMethod`) is synchronous, which it doesn't seem to be, since it uses callbacks – but *if* it is, your can simply put a return statement in front of it:

`return callToOutsideMethod(...`

If the inner function is asynchronous, you need to backtrack a bit and, if possible, get the return value of that function *before* actually creating the user. If that is not possible, see below.

**EDIT: Other hooks**

Remember that many more hooks than `onCreateUser` exist, both as part of [the API](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) and internally. Don't be afraid to look through the source files and use them to create your own solution; the inner workings of Meteor are relatively simple:

In the case of the `onCreateUser` hook, it is called inside the function `Accounts.insertUserDoc`, which is called by the different login services<sup>[1]</sup>. In your case, you need to be able to continue with the process inside `insertUserDoc` *after* your asynchronous stuff is done.

The only way I see how, with the current API, is by redefining the `insertUserDoc` function (may seem hazardous but similar stuff's been done before) – something along the lines of:

```
// Save the built-in function first
Accounts.insertUserDocFinal = Accounts.insertUserDoc;

Accounts.insertUserDoc = function (options, user) {
  callToOutsideMethod(some_arguments, function (data) {
    // Manipulate options and user objects?

    Accounts.insertUserDocFinal(options, user);
  });
};
```

*<sup>[1]</sup> with the options and user objects that is then passed on to `onCreateUser` (except they don't yet have the properties `_id` and `createdAt`).*

Comment: thanks for the response - the problem is this : i need data from the object used to create the user in order to run the callToOutsideMethod... and then I want Meteor to wait until I get the reply from the method and THEN make the user. So you're saying if callToOutsideMethod is asynchronous, this is impossible to do ?

Comment: If you redefine `insertUserdoc`, make sure that it is robust – that is, make sure that `insertUserDocFinal` gets called eventually.